# Adding number to p.value

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/KBcwe/2/)'s the fiddle. I'm trying to make it so when you press the button, it adds 1 to `#num`.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b').button({
        icons: {
            secondary: '.ui-icon-triangle-1-n'
        }
    });
    $('#b').click(function () {
        var x = '#num'.value;
        var u = x + 1;
        document.getElementById('#num').innerHTML = u;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting to values to the console to see what may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .It should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b').button({
        icons: {
            secondary: '.ui-icon-triangle-1-n'
        }
    });
    $("#b").click(function () {
        var x = parseInt($('#num').html());
        var u = x + 1;
        $('#num').html(u);
    });
});
```

Comment: This suggestion is binding a click on the body instead of the button: `$(this).click(function () {`

Comment: How can you use `$(this)`? Doesn't that refer to `document` in that context?

Comment: I am sorry. didn't notice that error. I copied the actual code and modified the error part.

Comment: @JJP Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Number($('#num').text());
```

You are not retrieving the value the correct way. Try the above

Comment: Should the leading '#' be removed?

Comment: @TGH Paragraph tags don't have a value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first part is working somehow (not sure what "button" is), try this:

```
$('#b').click(function () {
    var x = $('#num').text();
    var u = parseInt(x) + 1;
    $('#num').html(u);
});
```

Comment: Didn't vote down, but this won't work.  Paragraph tags don't have a value attribute.

Comment: I know. I didn't look at the fiddle. Just changed to text().

Comment: There's still a problem with this I'm afraid.

Comment: `x` is not a number...`+x + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle using jQuery's `data` function to store and increment the value:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyhpt/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b').button({
        icons: {
            secondary: '.ui-icon-triangle-1-n'
        }
    });
    $(this).click(function () {
       // var x = '#num'.value;
        var x = $('#num').html();
        var u = parseInt(x) + 1;
        document.getElementById('#num').innerHTML = u;//why not use $('#num').html(u);
    });
});
```

you can try this .

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes:

- `'#num'.value` is not valid. You should use `$('#num')` to get the jQuery nodes
- if you'd like to use `document.getElementById`, that should be `document.getElementById('num')`. Note there's no leading '#'
- to get or set HTML content in tags like p, div, span, use `.innerHTML` (for DOM nodes) or `.html()` (for jQuery nodes); to get input value from input, textarea, use `.value` (for DOM nodes) or `.val()` (for jQuery nodes)
- any value or HTML content in a node is a string, so you'd better change it into a number via `parseInt` (Javascript allows you add a string to an integer, but that's actually a string concatenate)

I'd like to change your codes in this way:

```
$(this).click(function () {
    var x = parseInt($('#num').html());
    var u = x + 1;
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = u;
});
```